# Cannot find the pachkage apache2-mpm-worker

Tags: apache, ubuntu

getting error on installing mpm-worker in ubuntu apache2.
How to fix this problem?

Comment: What is your version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

There is no apache2-mpm-worker package because the mpm_worker module is included by default when you install Apache on Ubuntu's newer versions. It is contained in the apache2-bin package that is a dependency of apache2:

```
sudo a2dismod prefork event php* && sudo a2enmod worker
```

If you see any errors like *cannot enable module* (similar), then let me know with the whole output. Make sure you enable php-fpm when you use prefork, if you wish to use PHP.

Comment: I was going through your answers, and I found a lot of things which I needed for security, and other stuff. Thanks a lot.